# Prove that if $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb C$, $f(0)=1/2$ and $|f(z)|\le|e^z-1/2|$ then $f(z)=e^z-1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I deduced that if $e^z-1/2=0$ then $f(z)=0$, but don't know how to proceed. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(z)/(e^z-1/2)$ for those $z$ where it is defined. What do you know about the remaining singularities?
Btw: The "<" sign doesn't make sense. Do you mean "$\leq$" instead?

Comment: on what sranthrop said : $f(z)/ (e^z-1/2)$ is meromorphic and bounded

Comment: Yes it was less or equal. I can see that it is meromorphic and bounded, and I know that if it was analytic on all the space it would be constant, how do I prove that the poles doesn't make a difference or that the function actually doesn't have poles?

Comment: A meromorphic function is analytic except at its (isolated) poles where it is unbounded, so a bounded meromorphic function is analytic.  Now you also proved that $f(z)$  has a zero at each zero (of order $1$) of $e^z - 1/2$, so really $f(z)/(e^z-1/2)$ is automatically entire (and bounded, and constant..)

Comment: how is that proven?

Comment: what ? the definition of a meromorphic function is that it is the quotient of two analytic functions, so it is analytic except at the zeros (of order $k$) of the denominator where it has some poles of order at most $k$

Comment: how is it proven that a bounded meromorphic function is constant? how do you know the order of the zeroes?

Comment: you need to work on a basic complex analysis course. $g(z)$ analytic means it has isolated zeros where $g(z) = \sum_{n=k}^\infty c_n (z-z_0)^n$ i.e.  $g(z) = (z-z_0)^k \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ with $ \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ analytic. If $h(z)$ is analytic, then $\frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$ is analytic except at those zeros of $g(z)$ where $\frac{h(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$, $m$ an integer and $f(z)$ analytic at $z_0$ and $f(z_0) \ne 0$. Of course $\frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$ bounded around $z_0$ means $m = 0$ so it is analytic at $z_0$

Comment: This statement is usually refered to Riemann. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity
Did you have this theorem in your course?